# Google Sheets Add-on error: authorisation is required to perform that action

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, add-on

I have an add-on that worked for years inside my domain/company until Google decided to change stuff.
I republished it and now I can run it but nobody else in the company can.
The error they receive is:

```
"Authorisation is required to perform that action".
```

I cannot pinpoint exactly where the error is because the GCP Log only tells me the function not the line, but it seems most of the times the error appears when showing a sidebar.

I do not use any kind of API, simply GAS but "just in case " I added in OAuth consent screen these scopes: `.../auth/script.container.ui and .../auth/spreadsheets`.

In Google Workspace Marketplace SDK OAuth Scopes I've just left the default.

Also I tried adding in appscript.json this (at top level):

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
```

What else can I try ?

Update: as requested in comments here's the offending code:

```
// clientside
google.script.run.
withSuccessHandler()
.withFailureHandler(failureHandler)  // failureHandler gets called
.aServerFunc() 

//serverside 
function aServerFunc(){
  Logger.log('REACHED') // NO REACHED APPEARS IN CLOUD LOGS !
  var docProp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();  
  return docProp.getProperty(key)
}
```

So I guess the problem is nobody else but me can run google.script.run in an add-on !

Update 2:
I've removed the PropertiesService calls so it's just a blank function on the server. So it's clear that nobody but me can run google.scripts.run.

Update 3:
As required in the comments here's the procedures I did to publish the add-on:
I created a google cloud project, then configured the OAuth consentscreen (with the same scopes as appsscript.json - see above list), then in Google Workspace Marketplace SDK I've set the script ID and deployment number and the same scopes and published.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share your sample code?

Comment: You might also want to check if this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269803/authorisation-is-required-to-perform-that-action-for-alert-popup-google-apps) would be helpful

Comment: I added now some code.

Comment: Do you have a simple trigger existing in your add-on code? If yes, you need to use installable trigger for authentication

Comment: I only have an onEdit which simply adds the menu, which works ( that's how my users start the add-on )

Comment: simple onEdit() trigger? can you try make it as an installable onEdit trigger?

Comment: That simple trigger is running succesfully. I see it in logs and it adds my menu. The problem is my users cannot run google.scripts.run

Comment: can you share the procedures you've done/followed when deploying your add-on?

Comment: sure. I added Update 3 section in description. I wouldn't want to make the question become too long so I only included what I thought  is important.

Comment: That simple trigger is running successfully. I see it in logs and it adds my menu. (Can you verify that the simple triggers also runs successfully when another user uses your add-on?)

Comment: Sorry for being pushy on checking this trigger. Since it is listed as a common issue for such error https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#authorization_is_required_to_perform_that_action

Comment: No problem. I appreciate that you're trying to help. Yes, I DID verify the simple onOpen trigger gets run for another user (I've added loging and checked GCP Log Explorer). Also onOpen simply adds the menu and the other users DO see the menu. Even show sidebar works. The error happens on the first google.scripts.run call. I did try to add an installable trigger but in that case I don't see the menu myself either, and I think it makes sense because installable triggers are per doc right ? I think the add-on cannot just add an installable trigger in each doc where it runs.

Comment: I found the issue and added the answer. Thanks for all the help though Ron. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the add-on was just fine !

It's just [this 4 years old bug that Google refuses to fix](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/69270374?pli=1) 
If the user is logged in with multiple accounts the default one will be used.

If the default account is non-domain and the add-on is restricted to a domain the add-on will fail to authorise.